# Gradient Tape is much slower than keras fit method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a simple Dense Layer on gradient tap and keras api both, but gradient tape has stuck on local minima but fit() method decresed loss till global minima, both have same optimizer and same learning rate and same loss function.
Can someone explain why this happens?

```
# Model Architecture...
dense1=tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=40)
dense2=tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
```

And Model Hyperparameters

```
# Model Hyperparameter...
epochs=10
batch_size=64
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
  return tf.keras.backend.sqrt(tf.keras.backend.mean(tf.keras.backend.square(y_pred - y_true))) 
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
train_gen=train_data_gen(batch_size)
```

Gradient tape :

```
@tf.function
def train_model():
  x,y=next(train_gen)
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape :
    predictions=dense2(dense1(x))
    vars=tape.watched_variables()
    loss=loss_fn(y,predictions)
    grads=tape.gradient(loss,vars)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,vars))
  return loss
```

Epochs on gradient tape :

```
# Training....

for epoch in range(epochs):
  losses=[]
  for batch in range(5000) :
    loss=train_model()
    losses+=[loss]
  print("Epoch : "+str(epoch+1)+"\nLoss : "+str(np.mean(losses)))
```

Now in Keras Api :

```
input_=tf.keras.Input(shape=(20))
t=dense1(input_)
t=dense2(t)
model=tf.keras.models.Model([input_],[t])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),loss=loss_fn)

model.fit_generator(train_gen,steps_per_epoch=5000,epochs=10)
```